# Conditionally relabelling row values

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I would like to write a script that will look at the value on data_id and data_raw_digits. If the value is the same for 3 columns, take the first non null value from the user_name column and relabel all columns associated with the particular data_id with the same value.

This is what I currently have

```
data_id   data_raw_digits    data_user_name    data_ended at    event_sequence
  1            0000               abc             112                 1
  1            0000                                                   2
  1            0000                                                   3
  1            0000                                                   4
  2            1111                                                   1
  2            1111               ccc             212                 2
  3            2222                                                   1
  3            2222               ddd                                 2 
  3            2222                               303                 3
```

Desired Output:

```
data_id   data_raw_digits    data_user_name    data_ended at    event_sequence
  1            0000               abc             112                 1
  1            0000               abc             112                 2
  1            0000               abc             112                 3
  1            0000               abc             112                 4
  2            1111               ccc             212                 1
  2            1111               ccc             212                 2
  3            2222               ddd             303                 1
  3            2222               ddd             303                 2 
  3            2222               ddd             303                 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do this with window functions:

```
select data_id, data_raw_digits,
       max(data_user_name) over (partition by data_id, data_raw_digits) as data_user_name,
       max(data_ended) over (partition by data_id, data_raw_digits) as data_ended,
       row_number() over (partition by data_id, data_raw_digits order by data_id) as event_sequence
from t;
```

Note:  In your result set, only the `event_sequence` distinguishes the rows.  The key point is that the ordering of the original rows is not preserved -- but there is no way to tell.

SQL tables represent unordered sets.  There is no ordering unless a column explicitly contains that information.  And you don't seem to have such a column.

Answer (score 0):

I would proceed as follows:

- for each of the columns to process (`data_user_name`, `data_ended_at`), use a window function in a subquery to rank records where the concerned field is not null within groups of records sharing the same `data_raw_digits` and `data_id`
- `LEFT JOIN` these results with the original table, and use `COALESCE` to replace null values with the value of the first record in the corresponding group

Query:

```
SELECT
    t.data_id,
    t.data_raw_digits,
    COALESCE(t.data_user_name, t_user_name.data_user_name) data_user_name,
    COALESCE(t.data_ended_at, t_ended_at.data_ended_at) data_ended_at,
    t.event_sequence
FROM mytable t
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        t.*,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY data_id, data_raw_digits ORDER BY event_sequence) rn
    FROM mytable t
    WHERE data_user_name IS NOT NULL
) t_user_name
    ON t_user_name.rn = 1
    AND t_user_name.data_id = t.data_id 
    AND t_user_name.data_raw_digits = t.data_raw_digits
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        t.*,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY data_id, data_raw_digits ORDER BY event_sequence) rn
    FROM mytable t
    WHERE data_ended_at IS NOT NULL
) t_ended_at
    ON t_ended_at.rn = 1
    AND t_ended_at.data_id = t.data_id 
    AND t_ended_at.data_raw_digits = t.data_raw_digits;
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gjCpbk6B44N2aj5RGfUJBt/1)**:

```
| data_id | data_raw_digits | event_sequence | data_user_name | data_ended_at |
| ------- | --------------- | -------------- | -------------- | ------------- |
| 1       | 0               | 1              | abc            | 112           |
| 1       | 0               | 2              | abc            | 112           |
| 1       | 0               | 3              | abc            | 112           |
| 1       | 0               | 4              | abc            | 112           |
| 2       | 1111            | 1              | ccc            | 212           |
| 2       | 1111            | 2              | ccc            | 212           |
| 3       | 2222            | 1              | ddd            | 303           |
| 3       | 2222            | 2              | ddd            | 303           |
| 3       | 2222            | 3              | ddd            | 303           |
```

Note: this was tested in a MySQL fiddle since, to my knowledge, there is no public aws athena fiddle available on internet; however this is quite standard SQL syntax that should work on most RDBMS, including yours.

Answer (score 0):

How about a good old self join with aggregation?

```
SELECT 
a.data_id as data_id,
a.data_raw_digits as data_raw_digits,
a.event_sequence as event_sequence,
max(b.data_user_name) as data_user_name,
max(b.data_ended_at) as data_ended_at        
from your_table a left join your_table b on a.data_raw_digits = b.data_raw_digits
group by a.data_id, a.data_raw_digits, a.event_sequence;
```